# Dateparser не понимает дату

Tags: python

Всем привет ! Я парсю дату одной страницы.И вот результат парсинга такой

> 2019-08-22T00:01:00Z

Код:

```
def get_data(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    item_datetime=soup.find('meta',{'itemprop':'dateCreated'})
    item_datetime=dateparser.parse(item_datetime,date_formats=['%d %B %Y %H'])
    print(item_datetime)
```

Такой формат для моей БД.Не подходит.Я решил использовать библиотеку `dateparser`
Но суть проблемы в том что `Dateparser`не понимает эту дату **`2019-08-22T00:01:00Z`** Я это понял судя по тексту ошибки:

> File
>   "C:/Users/Администратор/PycharmProjects/Task/parsers/bnewskz/bnewskz_parser.py",
>   line 13, in get_data
>       item_datetime=dateparser.parse(item_datetime,date_formats=['%d %B %Y %H'])
>
> raise TypeError('Input type must be str or unicode') TypeError: Input
>   type must be str or unicode
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

**Как можно исправить ошибку?**

Comment: Текст ошибки говорит о том, что вы отдаете парсеру неподходящий тип данных. Вам надо узнать, какой тип в `item_datetime`. Возможно там `None`, если ничего не нашлось.

Comment: Приведите пример тега `meta itemprop="dateCreated"`

Comment: @mkkik как я написал сверху.При парсинге вывелась дата такого формата 2019-08-22T00:01:00Z

Comment: @gil9red,meta content="2019-08-22T00:01:00Z" itemprop="datePublished" name="pubdate"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В `dateparser.parse` нужно передавать строку об этом говорится в ошибке: `TypeError: Input type must be str or unicode`, а у вас в `item_datetime` находится объект-тег.

Кроме того, [посмотрев описание](https://yandex.ru/support/video/partners/schema-org.html) мета-тега `itemprop=dateCreated` стало понятно, что его значение хранится не в теге, а в отдельном атрибуте, пример:

`<meta itemprop="dateCreated" content="2013-09-09T00:00:00">`

Соответственно, ваш код должен быть такой:

```
...
item_datetime = soup.find('meta', {'itemprop': 'dateCreated'})
if item_datetime:
    item_datetime = item_datetime['content']
    item_datetime = dateparser.parse(item_datetime, date_formats=['%d %B %Y %H'])
```

Остается вопрос формата даты, т.к. формат `'%d %B %Y %H'` не соответствует дате `2013-09-09T00:00:00` (`ISO 8601`).

Дата в `meta` вообще описывается форматом `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S` (`ISO 8601`), но `dateparser` должен сам суметь разобрать ее, поэтому:

```
...
item_datetime = dateparser.parse(item_datetime)
...
```

Comment: Благодарю !!))!